# Multi-Dimensional Arrays of Different Types in Swift

Tags: swift

I can easily write a multi-dimensional array in Swift when all the dimensions are of the same type, for example:

```
var totalTime : [[Int]]
```

How would I get the first dimension to be String and the second dimension Int?

Comment: That doesn't make sense: a multi-dimensional array is an array of arrays, so an Integer array would be an array of Integer arrays. What do you mean by "second dimension?"

Comment: I can accomplish what I need with two arrays, but I am curios as to whether there is a capability to do it in one multi-dimensional array. I want one dimension to store String values and one to store Int values. So for example, totalTime[0] would return "AstroCB" and totalTime[0][0] would retrieve 555. Just trying to see what is possible.

Comment: Ah, I see. You'd probably be better off going with erdekhayser's solution below.

Comment: I think you can find better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43385470/6864447)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would recommend using an array of tuples instead. What you want *could* be accomplished using an array of type Any, but it is not a good idea.

Instead, your array should be [[(String, Int)]]. This would also be more compact than what you want to do.

```
var myArray: [[(String, Int)]] = []
```

Comment: This causes a compile error I tried  var arrayTest : [[(String, Int)]]

Comment: @user3412502 Not sure why. This code works fine in my playground: 

`var arrayTest: [[(String, Int)]] = [];

arrayTest.append([("Hello", 2)]);

println(arrayTest);`

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the `= []`. This answers my questions! Thank you!

Comment: @erdekhayser, thanks. How can we modify values of these tuples? A simple tuple like myTuple = (123, "hello") can be modified like myTuple.1 = "changed". But myArrayOfTuples.append([(123,"how","to","modify")]) cannot be changed by myArrayOfTuples[0].1 = "no way", or myArrayOfTuples[0](1) = "no way", or myArrayOfTuples[0][1] = "no way". Thanks