# How can I declare a two dimension array with different types in swift?

Tags: swift, swift2

### Two dimension array - Ints

```
// Works!
var foo = [[Int]]()
```

### Two dimension array - Ints / Strings

```
// Neither work.  Halp!

var foo = [String][Int]() 
var foo = [String[Int]]()
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955017/multi-dimensional-arrays-of-different-types-in-swift), which leads me to believe that this can be done but is not advised.

Comment: `AnyObject`... maybe?

Comment: As suggested by the validated answer from the question you found: use tuple.  [[(String, Int)]]

Comment: How two dimension array with different types exist?????

Comment: which type should have an element in your array    arr[x][y] where x and y are indexes in different 'dimension'? your question doesn't have any sense for me.

Comment: Got it.  Yep.  Silly question.  2-dimension arrays by definition are never different types.

Comment: You can find better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43385470/6864447)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best practice here would be to use a tuple of two values of different types

```
var foo:[(String, Int)] = []
```

Or if you want to use values of different types

```
var foo:[(AnyObject, AnyObject)] = []
```

But if you want it to be a multidimensional array anyway, then just make it not type-specific:

```
var foo:[[AnyObject]] = []
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I understand this suggestion as a recommended practice.  I plan on accepting an answer that says either: "Yes, here's how you do it"  OR one that says "That is not possible in swift.  Use an array of tuples instead."

Comment: @AdamKalnas can you give us an example of this type or two dimensional array? in any programming language syntax ... for me it has no sense

Comment: @user3441734 he probably meant a 2-d array which you can populate with both Strings and Ints

Comment: @AdamKalnas Ok, I edited the answer, so you can mark it now