# Creating multi-dimensional arrays containing different types in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, types

I want to create a multi-dimensional array in Swift and following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955017/multi-dimensional-arrays-of-different-types-in-swift) on creating multi-dimensional arrays, I came up with:

```
var itemList: [[(String, Date, Double, Int)]] = []

let itemID = purchases["itemID"] as! String
let purchase_date = purchases["purchase_date"] as! Date
let purchase_date_ms = purchases["purchase_date_ms"] as! Double
let quantity = purchases["quantity"] as! Int

itemList.append([(itemID, purchase_date, purchase_date_ms, quantity)])
```

This all seems ok but when I try to get the data back out with:

```
var subPurchaseDate: Date
subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1]
```

to try to read the "purchase_date" value from the array I get the error "Cannot assign value of type '(String, Date, Double, Int)' to type 'Date'", and

```
switch itemList[iloop][0] {
        ...
        }
```

gives "Expression pattern of type 'String' cannot match values of type '(String, Date, Double, Int)'"

Any clues as to why it's not taking the value/type of the element that I'm trying to specify in `<array>[i][j]` but seems to be trying to take `<array>[i]`? What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have stored tuple value inside array. so, access the contents of a tuple by providing the index position .

```
subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1].0 // for string value
subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1].1 // for date
subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1].2 // for Double
subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1].3 // for Int
```

You can also access using it's named value.

```
 var itemList: [[(stringValue: String, dateVal: Date, doubleValue: Double, intValue: Int)]] = []

// append elements in `itemList`
itemList.append([(stringValue: itemID, dateVal: purchase_date, doubleValue: purchase_date_ms, intValue: quantity)])

// access using it's named value

subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1].stringValue // for string value
subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1].dateVal // for date
subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1].doubleValue // for Double
subPurchaseDate = itemList[0][1].intValue // for Int
```